# Working around https

Tags: url, https

I have quite a few custom webparts that redirect the user to specific content. It all works fine in HTTP context, but not in HTTP**S**, because I can't manage to get the S using `SPContext.Current.Site.MakeFullUrl`. I always get the unsecure protocol even if I'm acessing via https.

Since the content is usually displayed in the ModalDialog, it keeps on the "loading..." forever.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to refer to assets (scripts, images, stylesheets, etc.) that are available on both *http* and *https* you could use [scheme-relative urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583103/network-path-reference-uri-scheme-relative-urls) (`//`).

For example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will also work for assets located on your local SharePoint server, given you can access them with both protocols.

Comment: well... its part of the problem... (+1) but the main issue is redirecting to pages programatically... the url always come back http...

Comment: Can you not redirect using a relative URL?

Comment: no. In order to Modal dialog works you have to provide wither a html or a url for it... and the url cannot be relative... my case is kinda special because the content might not be in the same site-collection or even the same farm (we have a diferent farm for search, for example)

Comment: If your farms have different hosts or ports then using `OpenPopUpPage` will still break [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), because of the iframe it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `MakeFullUrl` for some reason? You can use `HTTPContext.Current.Request.Url` to build your site's relative URL like so:

```
String RelURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme.ToString() + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToString();
```

Comment: Yes. In order to Modal dialog work, you have to provide either a html or a url for it... and the url cannot be relative... my case is kinda special because the content might not be in the same site-collection or even the same farm (we have a diferent farm for search, for example)... another error happens because of the multiple AAM... sharepoint mixes them up... so yes i have to use MakeFullUrl...